# are generators supported in RPython?

Tags: python, generator, pypy, rpython

Are generators supported in RPython, because I just read something in PyPy's documentation that says they are not

[PyPy Doc - Coding Guide](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/coding-guide.html)

They seem easy to be translated to a statically typed language like C because every generation step is generated in function call.

Can someone explain why ? Or shed some more light on the subject. I am currently trying to learn the basics of writing RPython safe code.

Comment: This is an orthogonal question, but for what language are you writing an interpreter?  If you're not, then RPython is probably the wrong solution.

Comment: I am not writing an interpreter, as I said I want to know tips for writing safe RPython code, and while I was reading the PyPy Coding Guide I got intrigued by this generator thing

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generators are not supported simply because they were not needed at the time. The problem is not really having a roughly equivalent functionality in C, but needing to keep a frame of generator alive. Since RPython frames are translated to C frames, to support full python generators you would need some support for getting C frame and copy it somewhere else, or some equivalent.

This was simply hard/not needed and was not implemented.

Comment: When you say 'to keep a generator frame alive' do you refer of generators based on yield ?

Comment: Can't generators implemented with yeild be transformed in-memory to a class-based generator ? Which I suppose does not need a frame of it's own

Comment: @costy: I'm pretty sure such a transformation would be possible (similar to [lambda lifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_lifting) perhaps), but even then it would be a lot of work.

Comment: yes, I talk about generators based on yield. Transformation is of course possible, it's just that we didn't care. General-purpose iterators are more interesting and yet not supported by RPython btw